# Which one of these is correct?

Tags: word-order

I stumbled upon the following sentence in a vacancy ad on a newspaper.

1. "Please state the position on the subject that you are applying for."

Is this correctly put? I thought of the following alternatives but they don't seem right either. Please help me out.

2. "Please state the position that you are applying for, on the subject."
3. "On the subject, please state the position that you are applying for."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the ad is talking about an email reply to it, I would phrase it as

> Please state the position that you are applying for in the subject [of the email].

This word order is chosen so that the relative clause "that you are applying for" correctly modifies "position". As written, the relative clause seems to modify "subject", which is clearly wrong.